# bridge -swift.h file abruptly disappeared

Tags: xcode, swift

I am importing a swift file in an objective_c project and did it finely by labelling the Swift class with @objc and importing projectname-swift.h in the file communicating with it.
Yet I did not compile it for a month and now, when I try to do it, the compiler complaints it does not find the include file and so happens to the Swift class. I even tried compiling old versions but I got the same problem. Perhaps there was some change in Xcode or my installation.
[image: Xcode screen capture]!
What may I do to recover the situation?
[image: Configuration]!

I found there is nothing in the DerivedSources directory. I even tried deleting the full DerivedData folder but it rebuilt it with the DerivedSources still empty. 
[image: Derived Source]

Comment: You're not giving enough information. Show the actual code where the compiler complains. Also, check your build settings to make sure that the bridging header is being created.

Comment: The bridging header is useful for the reverse operation: including objective-c code in a swift project. I am including a save screen of the error in the original post.

Comment: No, there is another bridging header - this is the one that it can't find. It exposes Swift to Objective-C. It is created automatically.

Comment: I know, but I should need to include the virtual header Xcode creates for me according the project or module name: in my case both of the latter are named iPuja and thereafter the header file I wanted to include is named iPuja-Swift.h

Comment: Is it? You should look at it and see. You can find it by drilling down into your built app in the Intermediates folder.

Comment: I don't know why you are saying the project is named iPuja. I can _see_ in the screen shot that it is named iPuja Pro.

Comment: I am also including a screen capture of my configuration file.

Comment: I've added a screen shot showing how to see it.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. I went there by telnet and found it empty.

Comment: I've added to my answer a Terminal command that might be helpful.

Comment: And this is my result (or better lack thereof):
find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData -name "*Swift.h"
$

Comment: I removed the references to the swift files, but not the files themselves and I think I came closer to the problem. Now the compiler complaints that: the SDK 'iPhoneOS7.1.sdk' does not support Swift, whatever that may mean. I searched on the net for the full sentence but strangely found nothing. Any hint?

Comment: I'm glad you're back, because I thought of something and couldn't find this thread. I realized that the reason you are not seeing the automatically generated bridging header in your Derived Data folder is that you have not succeeded in building the app yet. So I was going to suggest that you comment out the references to this file, and whatever else needs commenting out, just so that you can build. Once you've built successfully, you will have the bridging header and you then look at its name as I advised earlier.

Comment: `SDK 'iPhoneOS7.1.sdk'` sounds like you've got a bad Base SDK build setting; I would check that if I were you. - Also what version of Xcode is this? And what is your build destination? In the screen shots, you are building for your device; can you now do that?

Comment: I think I found the issue. In order to try and verify the appReceiptUrl I took advantage of a library embedding the hard reference to the iOS7.1 SDK, so I thought better of softlinking the file it was searching to the current SDK. Objective C did not object, Swift evidently does. At first it refused to find many things, than I restarted Xcode and now it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad trick from Apple. Swift has nothing to do with it. When the project does not properly compile, sometimes the error reported mentions the impossibility of loading the Swift module. So far that has never happened to me again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying import something called `"iPuja-Swift.h"` but this is the wrong name. Your project is named **iPuja Pro** and the automatically generated Swift-to-Objective-C bridging header is named based on that. You have forgotten the "Pro" part.

If you are in doubt of the name of this bridging header, drill down into the built app in the Intermediates folder inside Derived Data and look at it. This is the name you need to match. Here's a Terminal command that should locate all the relevant headers so you can see their names:

```
$ find ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData -name "*Swift.h"
```

Here is a screen shot for a typical app; as you can see, I had to perform this examination because the header name was derived in a tricky way from the project name:

[image]

Comment: Nope, that was the old name. Now the name is simply iPuja, as it was when I submitted the app obviously compiling it rightly.

Comment: Dude, I am looking right at the screen shot you just posted! I can see the name for myself.

Comment: And in fact the name is iPuja, not iPujaPro. At any rate it does not even find iPujaPro-Swift.h

Comment: No, but I bet it will find `"iPuja_Pro-Swift.h"`. In any case just drill down and _look_ at the name of the header.

Comment: In fact there is nothing in /Users/fbartolom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/iPuja_Pro-geuzolcwoljzlocablkrjyizzrbj/Build/Intermediates/iPuja Pro.build/Debug-iphoneos/iPuja.build/DerivedSources

Comment: I changed the name of the project to reflect the one of the target, but the file is still missing.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old thread but anyway: Had the same problem. The file was there all the time and then suddenly apparently gone.
Turned out to be a simple error in one of the swift files that prevented that file from compiling; that error never showed up on the error list, though; instead there were dozens of complaints about the file "projectname-Swift.h" not existing.

Fixed that swift-file so that it would compile et voilà: "projectname-Swift.h" back again

Comment: It is a bad trick from Apple. Swift has nothing to do with it. When the project does not properly compile, sometimes the error reported mentions the impossibility of loading the Swift module. So far that has never happened to me again.

Comment: Thanks! The swift compiler strikes again.

Comment: It happens to me when I uninstall a pod component. In my swift file, the "import myPodFramework" don't show error but instead, the bridge file missing error appear. So you just have to remember where the framework was imported and remove the import lines in swift classes.